# Trying to configure throws error

Tags: reactjs, npm, aws-sdk-js

I am confused about aws-sdk for react, trying to configure it throws error which is a bit confusing, considering the object looks fine in the debugger, but the moment that I step over it throws error: `TypeError: Unable to get property 'config' of undefined or null reference`

the code:

```
import {AWS, CustomEvent, AMA} from 'aws-sdk';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {

    debugger;
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
    ...
```

I assumed that once imported the AWS included config object, and if I were to attach with debugger (at the `debugger;` line) the AWS object looks good and so does the AWS.config and further AWS.config.region is set to null, but if I step, it throws the above error....  Any thoughts what may be misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I solved it with:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```

For some reason it is the import { AWS } as opposed to import AWS that caused the error